# Comparing complex contours using moments

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour, image-recognition

OpenCV library has a method of copmaring pair of contours using moments. I'm wondering is it permissible to use a set of contours which describe the whole object instead of using one outer and closed contour?

It's obviously that inner contours can give us extra information for comparison (or may be it doesn't make so much sense).

E.G. If I want to compare building edge with the modeled sample, windows' borders would be separate from general contour. But their shape can also be informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this. It will be like a "bag of words" algorithm , where "words" will be your contours moments.